# Are there examples of creating new adult life without the normal biological process?

Tags: creation

Two examples:

Vishnu's avatara Narayana Rishi created Urvashi as a fully grown adult from hos thigh.

Siva creating Virabhadra from a lock of his hair.

Are there any others?

Comment: Manu Satarupa created by Brahmaji. Janaka who was churned from Nimi’s body. Prthu and Arci who appeared from Vena.